# How to generate a generic table view controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created a custom *TablePickerViewController* which is a subclass of *UITableViewController*. I'm using this class to display a list of object of a custom type *TablePickerItem*.

I'm using *TablePickerViewController* multiple times in my iOS application to show different kinds of lists where the user has to pick an item -- and then another view controller *MainViewController* should react on this selection and do something.

I've created this protocol and created a delegate property in the *TablePickerViewController*:

```
@protocol TablePickerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)tablePickerViewController:(TablePickerViewController *)controller
                    didSelectItem:(TablePickerItem*)item;
@end
```

When I setup a new *TablePickerViewController* in *MainViewController* it is also set as delegate -- than it will be notified when the user taps an cell in the table view.

The problem is that my *MainViewController* will setup multiple *TablePickerViewController* with different data (*TablePickerItem*). How should I setup my *MainViewController* to handle these multiple *TablePickerViewController*? Events from each of them will results in calling to the same protocol-method in my *MainViewController*.

Further I need to get the element which the *TablePickerItem* represents, as I need to know for instance the elements ID when acting in the `tablePickerViewController:didSelectItem` method. Should I just handle this by adding something like `@property (nonatomic) id element` to the *TablePickerItem* and set the original object into this property then creating it?

Maybe someone can give me an example on how to create an generic table view controller, if my solutions seems being done in the wrong way.

Comment: can you share this class. I am having the same need.if it is possible send it to z.a.khan.s3tech@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your set up, but if you have multiple pickers that feedback to the main controller then you could just have a reference to the picker e.g.

```
// MainViewController.m

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TablePickerViewController *picker1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TablePickerViewController *picker2;
// ... and so on. Obviously you know your problem domain so you can change
// the terrible naming above to something appropriate

@end

@implementation MainViewController


// ...

- (void)theMethodWhereYouSetUpYourPickers;
{
    TablePickerViewController *picker1 = [[TablePickerViewController alloc] init];
    picker1.delegate = self;
    self.picker1 = picker1;
    // ...
}

- (void)tablePickerViewController:(TablePickerViewController *)controller
                didSelectItem:(TablePickerItem*)item;
{
    if (controller == self.picker1) {
         NSLog(@"Something was picked in picker 1 %@", item);
    } else if (controller == self.picker2) {
         NSLog(@"Something was picked in picker 2 %@", item);
    }
}

// ...

@end
```